# PC suddenly cannot do layer 3 communications any more

Tags: windows, tcp, ethernet

A PC running Win7x64 always functioned properly until a power off yesterday. From then on, the IP layer of its 3 network interfaces (2 LAN, 1 WL) only partially function any more.

A backup was taken at 00:30, so the interface was necessarily OK until then. In the morning, I had to shut the PC down around 10:00. After the the restart, the 3 network interfaces ceased to function in the same partial way - making them all unusable.

Here's what I see:

- Needless to say, the interfaces have valid, unique static IPs, DNS, etc. (DHCP doesn't work)
- When booting Windows PE on that same machine, all 3 interfaces work perfectly, so there's no physical issue. Cable, switch etc were also tested with another machine.
- Wireshark shows that the interfaces see layer 2 and 3 packets like inbound ARP, UDP, broadcasts. But *almost no* IP and nothing else ever goes out. The PC also doesn't reply to ARP requests to it's own (static) IP, nor to pings nor anything else.
- A ping sent to the PC is not seen. A ping from the pc to the interfaces and 127.0.0.1 works.
- If I (re)configure it's static IP, it broadcasts (layer 3) a BROWSER request announcement and an NBNS Name query NB ISATAP<00>. It also sends broadcasts as UDP, ws-discovery to 239.255.255.250. But it doesn't seem to reply to anything, nor does the PC see any reply to this.
- Windows shows the interface as 'Unidentified network' with 0 packets sent of received - obviously incorrect given the above. I've obviously tried the usual stuff like removing the interface, fully removing and reinstall the Intel driver fatware, etc.
- Gigabyte GA-X99-UD5-Wifi motherboard, with built-in Intel I210 and (2) I218V adapters, and built-in Wifi; 64GB RAM.

The machine was not shut down for about a month, so possibly the problem was already there, although not appearing until the reboot. I have backups, but even a backup from days after the previous reboot (i.e. a good month ago) does not fix the issue, and restoring from so far back would be a problem.

Interesting problem maybe, but I cannot pinpoint what it may be.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the culprit to my problem: NPCap, Wireshark's capture interface. Lessons from this issue:

- Even if you have plenty of backups, it's not always possible to restore to a state weeks back;
- Go where the problem looks to be and dig further. In my own description, it was clear that layer 1 and 2 (OSI layers, remember?) were OK, but layer 3 was erratic, inconsistent.
- First step is to go back to something that works: in my case, a partition restore of 6 weeks ago;
- Then rebuild until it breaks, or in my case restore to the earliest point where it did not work: a full backup of about a month ago.
- Analyse the delta's between what worked and what did not. A tool that I use for years (Revo Uninstaller Pro) easily lists all components that were installed between the functioning backup of 6 weeks before, and the non-functioning one from 4 weeks before: the culprit was then easily found. NPCap is one of those few things that really can interfere with the IP stack.

I hope this helps someone.